# Wired connection continually dropping

Tags: usb, power, ethernet, connection

I've been having issues with the wired connection on my Pi. The connection keeps dropping out and then reconnecting constantly. About half the time it'll completely drop after a few minutes of this. I've used a few power supplies now, an Asus branded supply, HTC and a Belkin USB hub (F5U234) that is reportedly verified (http://elinux.org/RPi_Powered_USB_Hubs).

The disconnections occur on both Raspbmc and Raspbian. It doesn't seem to matter what is plugged into the USB ports, disconnections happen with nothing plugged in and with two things plugged in. Although when I connect the powered USB hub via USB, the ethernet immediately goes down (and stays down).

Are these symptoms of power supply issues?

Comment: This could very well be a power issue. Have you tested the voltage the pi is seeing. Also while debugging the problem you should not power the Pi from a usb hub.

Comment: I haven't tested the voltage, no. Will try and report back.

Comment: I basically have the same problem where pinging the raspberry pi's ip shows that it isn't responding about 80% of the time. I tried with USB power from my TV USB port and from my Roku's USB port. This issue seemed to go away when using a 0.7A microUSB power adapter, however it returned as soon as I stopped pinging. It did improve ping times from 30-40ms to 3-10ms.

Comment: I've checked the voltage and it's hovering around the 4.2 to 4.3v mark, with nothing else plugged into the pi. I've also checked my power supplies and they're ALL on the verified peripherals page. Tried different plug points and voltage is all the same. Worried it might be my houses power supply, I'll have to try it in another house.

Comment: @bucktronic let us know how it went.

Comment: Voltages in another (new build) house was the same as mine.  I'm having USB issues too and from what I've read, ethernet & usb issues can point to a fault on the Pi.

Comment: And what does consume less power: Ethernet or WiFi dongle? I have Ethernet dropouts with 3G dongle connected. Maybe it is better to switch to wireless connection?